# How to grep values after pattern in string

Tags: regex, sed, grep, pattern-matching

I need get values via grep from this strings:

```
<person_data>
    <person record_id="9209310" actual_date="2015-03-27" type="1" hash_last_name="TEST" hash_first_name="NAME" hash_middle_name="OTHER" hash_birth_date="1989-01-12" sex="2" marital_status="4" is_dead="2">
      <person_docs>
        <doc record_id="9257172" actual_date="2015-03-27" doc_type="1" hash_doc_serial="1234" hash_doc_number="7584933" hash_doc_issue_date="OCT 29 2016 13:00AM" doc_issue_auth="" />
```

I want get values after pattern - hash_

For example, I want get values - TEST, NAME, OTHER, 1989-01-12 from this string:

```
<person record_id="9209310" actual_date="2015-03-27" type="1" hash_last_name="TEST" hash_first_name="NAME" hash_middle_name="OTHER" hash_birth_date="1989-01-12" sex="2" marital_status="4" is_dead="2">
```

How to do it? Can I use grep or sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a look-behind:

```
grep -Po 'hash_[^"]*"\K[^"]*' file
```

This looks for strings like `hash_` + things up to `"` and prints what comes after and until a `"` is found.

#### Test

```
$ grep -Po 'hash_[^"]*"\K[^"]*' <<< '<person record_id="9209310" actual_date="2015-03-27" type="1" hash_last_name="TEST" hash_first_name="NAME" hash_middle_name="OTHER" hash_birth_date="1989-01-12" sex="2" marital_status="4" is_dead="2">'
TEST
NAME
OTHER
1989-01-12
```